# How to have a health check against an AML endpoint?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I have a running AML endpoint deployed on AKS cluster, looking like http://[IP address]:80/api/v1/service/modelscoring36/score.
This is the POST endpoint to respond any incoming model scoring request. Is there any way to check if the relevant AML service or attached AKS cluster is healthy?
In Asp.Net we is used to some dummy GET method constructed in one controller for this health check purpose.
Does AML service provide such health check approach? or any other suggestion?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To get the health check of the end points

1. install Azure ML SDK using Command Prompt

   pip install azureml-core
2. Get complete workspace details like subscription ID and other details. The requirements are mentioned below:

   **subscription_id = '<your_subscription_id>'

   resource_group = '<your_resource_group>'

   workspace_name = '<your_workspace_name>'

   ws = Workspace(subscription_id, resource_group, workspace_name)**
3. Using intermediate _get() method, we can get the health check details like below

   `for service in Webservice.list(workspace= ws):`

   ```
    service_properties = Webservice._get(workspace= ws, name = service.name)

    print('Service Name: {} - {}'.format(service_properties['name'], service_properties['state']))
   ```

The results look like below:

**Service Name: Model Name - Failed

Service Name: Model Name - Healthy

Service Name: Model name - Healthy**

Comment: BTW, this needs to run a python script. I'm also curios if some direct HTTP call is available for health check. If so I'd like to set up Azure Application Insight health check using direct HTTP call with better efficiency. Using python script may need more coding/configuration work to set up alert/monitoring. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't directly check <URI>/health or <URI>/score. Need to work with some script instead of direct calls.